# Chrome issue: Chrome not getting/drawing the image

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, src, drawimage

I am creating a  thumbnail gallery in html.
For getting the thumbnail images I do something like this

```
for(var i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    var thumbnails = $("<img/>").attr("src", "getPageImage.htm?page=" + temp[i]);
    $(body).append(thumbnails);
}
```

This is working fine.
Now I have a function which works on click event on these thumbnails, which is similar to following:

```
var nextImage;
$(thumbnails).click(function () {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    nextImage = new Image();
    nextImage.src = src;
});
```

Now I am drawing the nextImage object on a HTML canvas with

`ctx.drawImage(nextImage, 0, 0, 100, 130);`
This whole code is working with mozilla firefox but not the google chrome.
It seems like chrome is not sending the request again to the server for the src attribute of nextImage object.
Any alternate solutions?

Comment: oh god...please indent code blocks 4 spaces...only use back-ticks for inline code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an unused GET parameter in the picture's URL, which would be different everytime. I often use this trick to force browsers reloading an image.

```
var src = $(this).attr('src') + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();
```

..or...

```
var src = $(this).attr('src') + '?' + Math.random();
```

Comment: Sorry, but not working.
By appending the math.random(); or Date().getTime(); the url is being changed. Hence not working for mozilla also.

Comment: Do you already have a GET argument in the orginal URL? If so, add `&` instead of `?`.